# Password History checking with Umbraco 7.x backend "user" accounts (not member accounts)

Tags: api, passwords, umbraco, history

I am trying to work out how to configure the change password process for Umbraco users. I have a requirement for any new passwords for back end user accounts must be unique and can't be recycled.

How do I "break into" this change password process. I can see how you do it with the login process by inheriting from "umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider". How to you do this with Change Password?

Also... I'll need to salt and hash the prospective password with the same salt as the umbraco process. I have found a method for this:

HashPasswordForStorage in membership provider base. How do I use this? Does MembershipProvider inherit this class?

Any help gratefully received?

Comment: Would it make sense to set up an Azure AD to handle all that stuff for you instead? Hooking up Umbraco logins to AD I pretty easy, as far as I remember.

Comment: Are you suggesting handling this at the DB end. Didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't realise, Umbraco is ignoring custom membership providers as its now handled in UmbracoCustomOwinStartup.